# How to dynamically check certificates in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

Is there a way to use self-defined certificate check methods in Tomcat? Simply put, enable Tomcat to use my `checkServerTrusted(), checkClientTrusted()` for dynamic checking.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking about. Can you give a (real world) example where you'd like to use it? In general: You shouldn't implement cryptography yourself (and implementing any trust check is cryptography) unless that's exactly your business. The question assumes that it isn't.

Comment: e.g,  my CA sign certificates which are used inside our software. so, if you use default checking  mechanism, these certificates are not trusted. But they *should* be trusted because they are signed by my CA.

Comment: You'll have to add your CA to the keystore and mark it as trustworthy (and allowed to sign other keys)